# Ethernet magnetics separated from PHY, on external PCB

Tags: ethernet, signal-integrity

I am in a situation in which Ethernet magnetics will play a role in protection of an Ethernet port. Due to the design of the system, these magnetics need physical isolation from the PHY connected to them – with the exception of something like a flat-flex cable.

My thought was that this would likely work, as long as I could maintain 100Ω differential impedance and tight intra-pair skew from the PHY to the magnetics during routing. Since the pairs are part of a gigabit link, I would think some additional consideration would be required around guard vias, etc, too.

Here are my questions:

1. Are there any reasons I'm not thinking of as to why this wouldn't work?
2. Any other thoughts as to why this would be extremely ill-advised or difficult to get right with the right routing considerations?
3. Any other thoughts on routing considerations that I've missed?

Comment: What indirect effects? Are we talking ~2kV 1.5/50µs 20Ω surge here, say? Is a ground available? What does the equipment look like? How would it be wired in use, and what else would it be wired to besides the victim pair(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It could work, but depends on the implementation how it will go.
2. The suggested length from PHY chip to connector is about 2 inches, and suggested length from discrete magnetics to connector is about 1 inch. So if you can do it within those limits that would be no problem. Different appnotes say a bit different best practices.
3. Likely a lot. The flat flex interface must have impedance matched connector. And in addition to intra-pair skew, you need 20 mil inter-pair length matching too. It is difficult to say what you have or have not considered.

Comment: Right. I think using an impedance-controlled FFC or cable assembly for LVDS is the obvious match, here – one designed for 100Ω differential impedance, with a compatible 100Ω impedance-controlled connector. The inter-pair skew should be pretty easy to deal with, in this scenario – and I think I can realistically keep the distance between the PHY and magnetics pretty tight.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you really need to worry about is the magnetics themselves. You can get isolation at least up to 16kV (standard magnetics are ~2kv).

If you need more protection, TVS diodes can be used to short high voltage transients before and/or after the transformer.

Keep in mind that ethernet is already fairly robust against human body model ESD

Comment: Yeah; thanks for your input, here. I do know how to design the lightning protection – but physically locating the magnetics on a board separate from the PHY is the issue I'm currently facing.